# How to move laravel project to localhost in ubuntu?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, localhost

I know that what i am gonna asking question that is very easy but i am new to ubuntu and localhost services as well.So help me out from my question.

**question:** I created **laravel** project in **download** folder which contains only backend part.Now i want to merge front-end part as well.So i found that i have to move all files of front-end on **localhost**.I dont know how to open localhost directories and put all files in it.
So please give me hint to do that.

Comment: Are you asking about local host in ubuntu and directory to save that laravel project in that ??

Comment: @pravinpoudel yes

Comment: if you have problem on setting localhost in ubuntu i have given my answer on setting lampp in ubuntu .. please ask if you are asking other thing ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install Xampp for linux https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Then install it and change permission :

```
chmod 755 xampp-linux-*-installer.run
sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run
```

This will open the installer and just click “next” and it will install xampp files in /opt/lampp folder. You should first check if lampp is functioning properly. To test this,

```
  sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Let it start everything for you. Now just go to http://localhost and see it is working. We will need to setup security settings as well.

```
  sudo /opt/lampp/lampp security
```

Set all the passwords etc, and you are done!

Now you install composer :

```
 curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
 sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Now you need to get important dependencies of laravel - mcrypt.

```
  sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt php5-json
```

And now run:

```
  sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

To make sure it is running,

```
    php -i | grep mcrypt
```

It will output

```
    .......
    mcrypt support => enabled
    mcrypt_filter support => enabled
    .......
```

Now go to htdocs folder inside lampp and place your laravel project and it will work .

Comment: Thanks for answer,But i m getting error while accessing mysql database.It says "Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'The stream or file "/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel-projects/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied (SQL: select * from `files`)"

Comment: cd into your Laravel project.
sudo chmod -R 777 storage

Comment: please check if this help ??

Comment: I tried that command ,but again it shows me error "Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `files`)'"  while accessing mysql database.

Comment: No this is another another problem .. please check .env file in your project and put name of database and username and password which is your credential in localhost

Comment: Set your values in .env :

DB_HOST=localhost                     
                    DB_DATABASE=name_of_your_database
                    DB_USERNAME=root
                   DB_PASSWORD=""

Comment: Thanks man, Now new problem raised:).I inserted html,css,js (front-end) files in laravel's public folder.here i want to open these file through localhost.So how do i do that?

Comment: yes,But i have new problem that is related to connection b/w front-end and back-end.So can you help me?

Comment: yes boss  i can , i would love to help you  but comment isnot right place for this